# Django url error ( Redirecting to another url)

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have been learning django and i am having a problem with the url patterns.

i have the project **urls.py** as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('data/',include('data.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and i have "accounts app"  **urls.py** as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("register", views.register, name="register")
]
```

**views.py** of accounts app:

```
def register(request):
    return render(request,'register.html', {'title' : 'User Registration | Django'})
```

Basically my data app contains country, state and district models.

i have "data app" **urls.py** as follows:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("country", views.country, name="country"),
    path("state" , views.state, name="state"),
    path("district", views.district, name="district")
]
```

**views.py** of data app:

```
def country(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.is_ajax():
            
            obj_country_list = Country.objects.values("id" , "country")
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(obj_country_list)))
```

My error was when trying to access the **"data/country url"** inside the "register.html" page & the javascript function for fetching the is as follows:

```
function Country(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "data/country",
        //data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (Result) {
        $.each(Result.d, function (key, value) {
            $("#ddlcountry").append($("<option></option>").val(value.id).html(value.country));
        });
    },
    error: function (Result) {
        alert("Error in invoking the function");
    }
    });
}
```

I tried to inspect the page & the url it was trying was **accounts/data/country**.

When tried to change the url inside the header while inspecting the page to **data/country** i got the data.

Is there any way that the url can be changed or redirected to **data/country** instead of **accounts/data/country**.

Hope you have understood the problem.
Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url patterns for the **accounts app** :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path('data/',include('data.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply give forward_slash(`/`):

```
url: "/data/country",   <---- Here
```

Comment: No use. Its still redirecting to url : "accounts/data/country" instead of url: "data/country ".

Comment: I assume that you still need a button or something like that to call that ajax function, so you could add a property for that button like `data-target-url="{% url 'country' %}"` and before I forget, also an `id` for the button e.g. `the-btn`. the  in the ajax function write it like: `url: $("#the-btn").data("target-url")` and that's it.

Comment: Thank you for your interest but solved the problem by myself. i just simply added the ``data app``  url inside the accounts url patterns.